# How can i get entire role assignments from SP 2010 using C# and the client object model interface?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010, active-directory

I've been trying to get all the RoleAssignments using the COM interface. the problem is that i get the AD user group names instead of the actual users inside the groups.

my code looks something like this:

```
ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(#SiteURL);

RoleAssignmentCollection Roles = cc.Web.RoleAssignments;

IEnumerable<RoleAssignment> newRoleAssignmentsCollection = cc.LoadQuery(Role.Include(role => role.Member));

AsyncDelegate execDel = new AsyncDelegate(cc.ExecuteQuery);

execDel.BeginInvoke(arg => { cc.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (RoleAssignment RoleAssign in newRoleAssignmentsCollection)
{ 
    RoleAssign.Member.LoginName; // <------- Here is my problem!!! 
}

}, null);
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get the users which are inside the Active Directory group?

Thanks in advance, Itay.

Comment: you need to get all users from particular group? or get all users that have particular rights?

Comment: All users that have paticular right would help. but i can manage with all the users from particular group as well...